# Sorting the files according to filename in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, sorting

**Sorting the file with their integer filenames.**

1. I need to sort files in *Python* according to the file names **ascendingly** using the ***integers in the filename***. The sort function in *python3* sorts the filename as **1**,11,12,13,......,19,**2**,21,22..... etc.
2. There are some files with the exception in their filenames, for example, some files are named 1a.htm, 3a.htm, 4a.htm. I want to ignore these files and don't want to include these files in my final sorted list of files.
   [The files and folders I want to sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oABR.png)

Normal sorting issue:

```
    import bs4
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import os,glob

    root='data_sample_gnc/'
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for file in sorted(files):
            if(file.endswith('.htm')):
                print(file)
```

> Output 
>   1.htm
>   10.htm
>   11.htm
>   12.htm
>   13.htm
>   14.htm
>   15.htm
>   16.htm
>   17.htm
>   18.htm
>   19.htm
>   1a.htm
>   2.htm
>   20.htm
>   21.htm
>   22.htm
>   23.htm
>   24.htm
>   25.htm
>   26.htm
>   27.htm
>   28.htm
>   29.htm
>   3.htm
>   30.htm

Exception issue:

```
    import bs4
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import os,glob

    root='data_sample_gnc/'
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
        sorted_files=sorted(files, key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0]))
        for file in sorted_files:
            print(file)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-2881098be594> in <module>
      5 root='data_sample_gnc/'
      6 for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
----> 7     sorted_files=sorted(files, key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0]))
      8     for file in sorted_files:
      9         print(file)

<ipython-input-45-2881098be594> in <lambda>(x)
      5 root='data_sample_gnc/'
      6 for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
----> 7     sorted_files=sorted(files, key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0]))
      8     for file in sorted_files:
      9         print(file)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1a'
```

Thanking in advance for your help. :) xD

Comment: Split the dot and use if condition isalnum for first element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the non-numerics then sort.

**Example (using file string)**

```
files = "1a.htm, 1b.htm, 1.htm 10.htm 11.htm 12.htm 13.htm 14.htm 15.htm 16.htm 17.htm 18.htm 19.htm 1a.htm 2.htm 20.htm 21.htm 22.htm 23.htm 24.htm 25.htm 26.htm 27.htm 28.htm 29.htm 3.htm 30.htm"

sorted_files = sorted(filter(lambda x: x.split('.')[0].isnumeric(), files.split()), key= lambda y: int(y.split('.')[0]))

print(sorted_files)
```

In the above files.split() convert the string to a list of files (e.g. )

**Output**

```
['1.htm', '2.htm', '3.htm', '10.htm', '11.htm', '12.htm', '13.htm', '14.htm', '15.htm', '16.h.htm'tm', '17.htm', '18.htm', '19.htm', '20.htm', '21.htm', '22.htm', '23.htm', '24.htm', '25.htm'7.htm, '26.htm', '27.htm', '28.htm', '29.htm', '30.htm']
```

**Example Using Posting (file list)**

Posting obtains the list of files from:

```
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
```

files already type , so we do not perform a split to get a list.

```
 sorted_files = sorted(filter(lambda x: x.split('.')[0].isnumeric(), files), key= lambda y: int(y.split('.')[0]))

# Above changed from files.split() to just files
```

Comment: you have a type in output '1315.htm' edit: Actually I'm not sure how you even get that output from that input

Comment: @AlbertoPoljak--thanks.  Not sure why earlier runs were producing that.  Output is correct now I believe.

Comment: @DarrylG I have a list of files,  not the string of file names as you have taken as input. And i get the error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'.

Comment: @antonyjames--updated my posting for your case.  Basically, since you have a list of files, you use files rather than files.split() in the sort expression.